# Вычисление разницы времени в DataFrame в столбце где дата/время представдены в виде строки

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Имеется набор данных `df` c одним из признаков `time_and_date` который имеет тип `object` Данные выглядят так:

```
     time_and_date
  0  21OCT17:00:00:00   
  1  12OCT17:12:24:07   
  2  05DEC17:00:00:00   
  3  21OCT17:00:00:00   
  4  24OCT17:13:14:24
```

Нужно вычислить разницу между самым поздним датой-временем и самым ранним.

Пробую код:

```
df['Разница между самой ранней и\
   самой поздней транзакцией клиента']=df.groupby('cl_id')['TRDATETIME'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()).dt.days
df.head()
```

Где df.groupby(cl_id) - это просто группировка по клиенту.

Выходит ошибка: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Ошибка, видимо, в типах данных, как конвертировать в нужный временной формат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [156]: df
Out[156]:
      time_and_date  cl_id
0  21OCT17:00:00:00      1
1  12OCT17:12:24:07      1
2  05DEC17:00:00:00      2
3  21OCT17:00:00:00      2
4  24OCT17:13:14:24      2
```

Сначала добавим столбец с типом данных `datetime`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_and_date'], format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
```

получилось:

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]:
      time_and_date  cl_id                date
0  21OCT17:00:00:00      1 2017-10-21 00:00:00
1  12OCT17:12:24:07      1 2017-10-12 12:24:07
2  05DEC17:00:00:00      2 2017-12-05 00:00:00
3  21OCT17:00:00:00      2 2017-10-21 00:00:00
4  24OCT17:13:14:24      2 2017-10-24 13:14:24
```

теперь можно посчитать разницу между датами:

```
In [153]: df.groupby('cl_id').apply(lambda x: x['date'].max() - x['date'].min())
Out[153]:
cl_id
1    8 days 11:35:53
2   45 days 00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вылетела из головы эта конвертация